# django-guardian custom user permissions

Tags: python, django, django-models, user-permissions, django-guardian

### Setup

I've just started working with [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) and have straight away run into some obstacles. I'm using custom users by extending the AbstractBaseUser class. I followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) example to setup my models.py and admin.py. I also followed the [developers guide](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) configuration guide to setup guardian.

---

### Problem

django-guardian throws a `AttributeError: type object 'MyCustomUser' has no attribute 'groups'` error (MyCustomUser is my custom user class) whenever I try to **get** permissions pertaining to a user i.e. when I add a permission, it goes straight into the `guardian_userobjectpermission` table, like it should. However, calls to `get_perms` throw the mentioned error.

The same error appears while trying to edit permissions via the admin page. (progmatically added permissions don't show up here. :/) I wrote a small manage.py task to test it:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        user1 = MyCustomUser.objects.filter(username='pankaj')[0]
        checker = ObjectPermissionChecker(user1)

        # model on which permissions are applied
        stream = Stream.objects.filter(uuid='001')[0]   

        # works on the database level, doesn't show up on admin page
        assign_perm('read_stream', user1, stream)

        # error
        print 'read_stream' in get_perms(user1, stream)

        # error
        print checker.has_perm('read_stream', stream)

        # error
        print checker.get_perms(stream)

        # works on the database level, doesn't show up on admin page
        remove_perm('read_stream', user, stream)

        # ALWAYS returns True, irrespective of whether permission granted or not
        print user.has_perm('read_stream', stream)
```

---

### Possible Solution

1. There might be a problem with setting up the authentication backend. I currently have it set to:

   AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

   ```
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

   'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
   ```

   )
2. Maybe implementing a custom user => changing/implementing custom groups? Currently I have admin.site.unregister(Group) in admin.py, but changing it doesn't help.
3. As the developer has [warned](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/custom-user-model.html), guardian might not be compatible with custom users?

Answer (score 0):

According to django-guardian documentations [here](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/custom-user-model.html). Gaurdian was depending heavily on the old fashion of django user model. But you can get through it, if you extend `AbstractUser` model, or defined ManyToMany relation with auth.Group could groups in your authentication model.

> `django-guardian` relies heavily on the `auth.User` model. Specifically it was build from the ground-up with relation beteen `auth.User` and `auth.Group` models. Retaining this relation is crucial for `guardian` - **without many to many User (custom or default) and auth.Group relation django-guardian will BREAK.**